# Prerequisites to tackle Multiplicative number theory (Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions)

Tags: soft-question, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

I have been studying for a while abstract algebra, group theory and complex variables (at the basic level of the books of [Fraleigh](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/933251903X), [Humphreys](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534590) and [Gamelin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950699).

I have also surfed through some books in number theory and know the basics, but somehow I feel that *Multiplicative Number Theory* is a little far from the usual approach that the basic number theory books tackle.

What would be your advise to tackle this [Davenport's monograph](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950974) for selft-study? Particularly I am interested in understanding the proof Dirichlet Theorem on Arithmetic progressions.

Comment: If you know some complex analysis, group theory, and algebra, then you absolutely have everything necessary to dive right into Multiplicative Number Theory or Davenport's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have what it takes indeed already.

I would recommend the book "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" by Apostol, https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Analytic-Number-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387901639/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1523644851&sr=8-1&keywords=Analytic+Number+tHeory+apostol.

In particular Chapter 7 is what you are after and it gets there bit by bit, just for some extra help.

Comment: I think one should note that Apostol carefully avoids using any complex analysis or sophisticated real analysis until the final portion of his book. This makes it a nice introduction, but perhaps overly simplistic for someone who already knows complex analysis. But I learned from Apostol once upon a time, and I like it.